# Fish weird endline character at end / Fish shell outputs ⏎

Tags: python, terminal, console, stdout, fish

I have a Python script that prints some numbers, like this:

```py
results = [42, 21, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2]
for number in results:
    print(number, end=' ')
```

In the console, the output of this script is:

```
42 21 64 32 16 8 4 2 ⏎
```

Why is there a weird character at the end?

My IDE is LunarVim. My shell is Fish.

Comment: Your IDE/shell is just highlighting an otherwise "invisible" return character…!?

Comment: See [fish shell outputs ⏎ (i.e. an "abandon line") during startup on smaller terminal sizes](https://superuser.com/questions/1641529/fish-shell-outputs-i-e-an-abandon-line-during-startup-on-smaller-terminal) on Super User

Comment: Thanks! So it indicates that there's no trailing newline?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. So simply adding `print()` at the end of your script should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

[Fish shell outputs ⏎](https://superuser.com/questions/1641529/fish-shell-outputs-i-e-an-abandon-line-during-startup-on-smaller-terminal)

This is essentially fish's way of telling you that there is no trailing newline or "\n". Using print() will probably not result in this. In bash, the terminal may start after the output, instead of the next line.